# How do I write a kanji with the pen on the Surface Pro 4?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-surface, input-languages, japanese, microsoft-surface-pro-4

In a previous Windows 10 version I could select to handwrite English words or Japanese kanji from the on-screen keyboard after tapping the keyboard icon in the right-hand corner. That option appears gone in version 1709. How do I handwrite Japanese kanji with this Surface Pro 4?

Comment: Which previous version precisely?

Comment: There have been too many updates, so I cannot say more precisely than "January - November 2017". I used to be able to write the kanji via a certain pen-keyboard that now appears absent (or difficult to find). I switched to Ubuntu for a few months, then when I returned to this device and updated it I cannot find the pen-writing input option that used to be easily selectable from the touch keyboard option.